# Android ListView custom layout for selected item

Tags: android, android-listview

How to make custom ListView item being shown on selection?
Selected item should not only change background color (as show many examples here and in blogs), but also have another layout with additional data.

Comment: You can have custom listview using a custom adapter. "custom ListView item being shown on selection". This part of your question is unclear to me.

Comment: Do you mean you want to change the item row of selected item on onPress event?

Comment: Yes, I have custom adapter. And yes, I want to change item on onPress event.

Comment: yes it is possible, you have to "detect" state selected and change the layout to "extended" one

Comment: and dont use any MotionEvents as the selected state can be entered by trackball as well

Comment: To add to that previously stated points, consider creating both views and just hiding the extended one initially then reverse the state. I would think that this is faster, because inflating/adding/replacing costs resources (time). But the Show/Hide, inflates only about 10 in total (number of rows displayed in one screen, due to row reuse). That is my understanding, if anyone is aware that I am wrong, please enlighten us, cheers.